# Memory error when creating a large matrix on Gcloud machine but not on slow mac

Tags: python, numpy, google-cloud-platform

I need to create a large numpy matrix to store processed images (29316 images with height/width of 288/512 and 3 color channels). I have no problem executing this line on my slow Mac computer, but I get a "MemoryError" when trying to execute it on the Google Cloud machine (8 vCPUs, 64 GB memory). The GPU is a Tesla K80. **How is that possible and what can I do to fix?**

```
   x = np.zeros((29316, 288, 512, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

To create this array, you are creating `29316*288*512*3=12968460288` numbers.

Suppose every number uses `8B`(64bits), you need at least `103747682304B`. That equals to `103747682304B=101316096KB=98941.5MB=96.622558594GB`

So if I doesn't make some mistakes, I am wondering how could you execute this command on your *slow* Mac computer?

Comment: Is it possible that on my mac disk space is used as virtual memory?

Comment: @megashigger Surely it is possible, but do you really allocate over 90GB virtual memory(suppose your mac's physical memory is 8GB)? It sounds... unbelievable.

Comment: It sounds like a lot but I have no sense of whether that's possible or not. I know for a fact that I can execute that line on my mac though. :S :(

Comment: @megashigger That might be true, I searched it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html This article says OS X will use all of the available space on the machine’s boot partition as virtual memory.

Comment: Can I replicate that behavior on a Google Cloud machine?

Comment: @megashigger I think not, you need to manually allocate virtual memory on Linux system.